# How to send a row of data from a table into another table on a different sheet, then delete from the original table, in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

In Excel I have a table with a range of `A1:F12` and I wanted to have a macro that could transfer any row (for example `A2:F2`) from the data into another table of a separate sheet in the same workbook. Then once completed, delete the data transferred from the original sheet so it's only on the second table.

Comment: Hello, what did you try? Keep in mind this is not a free scripting service.

Comment: I used a few codes but the main problem I kept running into was the second table having too many extra slots and/or the data being moved getting deleted on the second table as well. this is what I am currently using at the moment Range("Table35").Select
    Range("B8").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B8").Select
    Range("Table35").Delete

Comment: Please edit the question whenever you add any additional details.

Comment: record a macro to do that ... edit the backing after recording to customize it

Answer (score 0):

The below macro will copy all the data starting from row 2 (assuming row 1 are the headers) from source sheet "Sheet1" and paste it to the target sheet "Sheet2". The data from source sheet will always be appended at the first empty cell from A column at target sheet. After the content is pasted, it will be deleted from source sheet. If there are empty cells in A column, this macro will not work correctly as it depends on cells in A column whether they are empty or not. Adjust it to your needs

```
Sub MacroTestAtoF()
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim targetRow As Long

Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
targetRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 2 To lastRow
    sourceSheet.Range("A" & i & ":F" & i).Copy targetSheet.Range("A" & targetRow & ":F" & targetRow)
    targetRow = targetRow + 1
Next i
sourceSheet.Range("A2:F" & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```